# Css non repeating gradients with transparency

Tags: css, size, transparency, gradient

I'm trying to get a transparent gradient of a certain size on the header of my website. I'm horrible with CSS (And CSS3, etc.) so I was wondering if anybody could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) and adjust gradient as per your requirment from there. Then after it will show you some css codes. Just make it copy and paste in your css file.It will make your gradient easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this site for generate your gradient background and this ok in IE 6,7,8,9 and other browser

```
www.colorzilla.com
```